# Do PostSharp dependencies need to be distributed?

Tags: dependencies, postsharp

The main question I have is whether PostSharp dependencies need to be distributed with dlls that use it.  I assume not since PostSharp works at compile time rather than runtime but I am about to propose some ideas to my boss and I would just like some verification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, PostSharp works on the build system to do it's work. After that, you only need to distribute PostSharp.dll which should already be in your output folder.